# Specify walkable area in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to limit the area where my player can walk. In this case only on red segments.

And I want to use 2D sprites as background images not 3D models. But my main player would be in 3D

Can I use NavMesh here? Or should it be done with Tilemap? Or should I place some 3D objects above it?

[here is another scene that I would like to understand how to build](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*kyEapu2ctXlt20tO.jpg)

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding invisible colliders attached to an empty gameobject to prevent your character from walking into certain areas.